# Saving workflow as template and importing to another site collection is not working

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-template

I've created primitive reusable workflow (with the only action `log to history list`) using SPD 2010. Under option `Pick a base content type to limit this workflow to` I leave `All` content types.
After creating I pressed `Save As Template` SPD ribbon button to save my workflow as .wsp in site assets library. Next I downloaded this wsp and deploy it to my farm. Next I went to another site collection and activate workflow feature - name sounds something like `Workflow template <name> from web template <name>`. All ok at this stage.

But when I was trying to associate this workflow to a custom list, in the list of available workflows my template is not presented. But feature activated successfully, I can open this site in SPD and see my workflow under `Workflows` option.

But why I can't see my imported workflow in the `Add Workflow` page of a list?
I was trying to associate workflow with list through SPD, but got `Null reference exception`

Answer (score 1):

maybe the feature is not activated in the site level and only activated in the site collection level

Answer (score 0):

Try a common base content type like `Document` and re-deploy the wsp to see if this works on a Document Library and if this removes the Null Reference Exception

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you probably did not publish the WF template in the first place. There are 2 possible solutions:
1.Publish the WF template before saving it in the source
2.In the destination, after activating the solution, open the WF template with SPD and publish it

Comment: Please don't add the same answer on different questions. [Ref](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/110135/6382)