# Not able to use custom workflow template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

I want to use a 2013 reusable workflow, which I have installed from a .wsp solution package.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Create very simple workflow(2013 reusable) in SPD2013
2. save the WF as a template and download it
3. upload the solution to a site, activate it
4. go to site features and activate the workflow feature i uploaded

But when I try to add a workflow to a list, I cannot see the template which I have uploaded.

[Imported workflow activated as feature does not show up in Manage site features page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36383/imported-workflow-activated-as-feature-does-not-show-up-in-manage-site-features)

In the above link, it is mentioned that there could be a problem with the languages, but according to me that couldnt be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you probably did not publish the WF template in the first place. There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Publish the WF template before saving it in the source
2. In the destination, after activating the solution, open the WF template with SPD and publish it